# How to convert a pandas dataframe to a nested named tuple with aggregation level

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I am looking for a way to create a nested named tuple from a pandas dataframe.
The object `d` is the expected output. I am not sure if the aggregation must be done directly in Pandas then the conversion to `NamedTuple` should be done afterward?

```
from typing import NamedTuple
from typing import List
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [["tom", 10, "ab 11"], ["nick", 15, "ab 22"], ["juli", 14, "ab 11"]]
    People = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age", "PostalCode"])

    names = list(People[["Name"]].itertuples(name="Names", index=False))
    postal_codes = list(
        People[["PostalCode"]].itertuples(name="PostalCode", index=False)
    )

    # ...
    # ... The code after produce the expected output even if the name of the NamedTuple doesn't matter

    PeopleName = NamedTuple("PeopleName", [("Name", str)])
    PeoplePC = NamedTuple("PeoplePC", [("PostalCode", str)])
    Demography = NamedTuple(
        "Demography", [("names", List[PeopleName]), ("postalcodes", PeoplePC)]
    )

    d = [
        Demography(
            [PeopleName(Name="tom"), PeopleName(Name="juli")],
            PeoplePC(PostalCode="ab 11"),
        ),
        Demography([PeopleName(Name="nick")], PeoplePC(PostalCode="ab 22"),),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then apply a function (`to_nested_tuple`) over the groups:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List

import pandas as pd

data = [["tom", 10, "ab 11"], ["nick", 15, "ab 22"], ["juli", 14, "ab 11"]]
people = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age", "PostalCode"])

PeopleName = NamedTuple("PeopleName", [("Name", str)])
PeoplePC = NamedTuple("PeoplePC", [("PostalCode", str)])
Demography = NamedTuple("Demography", [("names", List[PeopleName]), ("postalcodes", PeoplePC)])


def to_nested_tuple(k, g):
    peoples = list(g['Name'].to_frame().itertuples(name='Person', index=False))
    return Demography(peoples, PeoplePC(k))


d = [to_nested_tuple(*item) for item in people.groupby('PostalCode')]

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
[Demography(names=[Person(Name='tom'), Person(Name='juli')], postalcodes=PeoplePC(PostalCode='ab 11')), Demography(names=[Person(Name='nick')], postalcodes=PeoplePC(PostalCode='ab 22'))]
```

Comment: This code assume that only one attribute is retrieved from the dataframe, what would be the option to retrieve more than one field, something like `...g[['firstname', 'lastname']].to_frame()...` - correct me if I am wrong but this does not produce a `Series ` - Thanks

Comment: In case you want more than one field drop the `to_frame()` call. Does it makes sense?